# Merging tags [gmail] and [google-apps-email]

Tags: support, tags

Tags [gmail](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/gmail) and [google-apps-email](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/google-apps-email) refer to the same thing as the email service management features like DNS record management, email routing are out of scope in Web Applications.

It's worth to say that both tags were used together in several questions. There are [85 questions double tagged](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/google-apps-email+gmail) this way while there are [159 questions with google-apps-email tag](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/google-apps-email) Vs. [2591 questions with gmail tag](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/gmail)

As a Web Application there are very few differences but most of them doesn't change the UI or the change have minimum impact and it's explained in the [Gmail Help](http://support.google.com) so in for both tags the source form many questions is the same.

In Gmail for Work (one of the names that Google use to call Gmail edition for Google Apps)

- Custom logo instead of the Gmail logo
- Slight different tab names for only one tab.
- Few features could be blocked by the organization administrator

Reference

- [What are tag synonyms and merged tags? How do they work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/70710/289691)

Comment: @pnuts: I added a link to a Meta SE faq. I should re-read this question and the linked post (: I'll try to do this tomorrow.