# Google Apps is now "G Suite"

Tags: discussion, retag-request, clean-up, tag-synonyms

https://www.google.com/gsuite or, if you prefer, https://gsuite.google.com/

> Introducing G Suite from Google Cloud. A set of intelligent apps including Gmail, Docs, Drive and Calendar to connect the people in your company, no matter where in the world they are.

(I'll spare you my feelings about Google's neverending rebranding of **everything** *except* search and Gmail.)

This appears to be a complete rebranding of their various **Google Apps** suite. They have subcategories for Basic, Business, Enterprise, but also [**G Suite for Education**](https://blog.google/topics/education/introducing-g-suite-education/), [**G Suite for Government**](https://gsuite.google.com/industries/government/) exists (which seems to be the same as for business) as well as other "specialty" industry stacks (e.g., Healthcare) but they all ultimately seem to have the same suite of tools.
 [**Google for Nonprofits**](https://www.google.com/nonprofits/) contains [**G Suite for Non-Profits**](https://www.google.com/nonprofits/products/apps-for-nonprofits.html), but also includes information about Google Ad grants and other things that nonprofits might be interested in from Google.

G Suite includes:

- Communicate

  - Gmail
  - Hangouts
  - Calendar
  - Google+
- Store

  - Drive
- Collaborate

  - Docs
  - Sheets
  - Slides
  - Forms
  - Sites
- Manage

  - Admin
  - Vault

We need to work out how we need to re-organize our tags etc. What should stay. What should go. What needs to be renamed.

Part of the consideration is that sometimes (not always) the answer to a user's question will depend very much on whether it's the consumer version of the app, or the "G Suite" version of the app. How can we effectively help users help themselves by indicating which they're asking about?

From what I can see, **G Suite** contains all of the same tools that Google Apps used to. Ultimately, it doesn't matter what "X" stands for: G Suite for X is pretty much the same functionally. (Pricing is a different matter, and probably none of our concern here.)

Comment: Related: http://meta.webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/3832/merging-tags-gmail-and-google-apps-email

Comment: An official help article about the name change: [About the name change from Google Apps to G Suite](https://support.google.com/a/answer/7126147?hl=en). By the way, Google Apps Script (GAS) also changes it's name, "now" it's Google Script, but the specific sites/documentation are not updated yet.

Comment: *groan* just as we were done with the Docs/drive/shenanigans..

Comment: @Sathya next thing you know, they'll be changing their *company name*...

Comment: And here we go again: G Suite is now Google Workspace

Answer (score 1):

Here's how I think we should fix this.

- <del>Get a good excerpt and tag wiki for [g-suite](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/g-suite)</del>
- Make [google-apps](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/google-apps) and [google-apps-for-work](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/google-apps-for-work) synonyms of [g-suite](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/g-suite)
- Make [google-apps-email](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/google-apps-email) a synonym of [gmail](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/gmail) (as suggested in [this question](https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3832))
- Google Apps Sync is now [G Suite Sync for Microsoft Outlook](https://support.google.com/a/users/answer/153866). Therefore, rename [google-apps-sync](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/google-apps-sync) to [g-suite-sync](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/g-suite-sync). (I would suggest [g-suite-sync-for-outlook](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/g-suite-sync-for-outlook) but I believe it's too long.)

Comment: I've take a run at a [wiki for G Suite](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/tags/g-suite/info). It could stand a bit of expansion and more polish.

Answer (score 0):

I consider that the Communicate, Store and Collaborate G Suite components are included in the scope of SE Web Applications, but the Admin components not. The last are Web UIs to manage enterprise services in a similar way that several DNS hosts offer a Web UI to manage DNS records as the same occur well with other cloud services.

Regarding the Communicate, Store and Collaborate G Suite components I think that we should merge the tags when there is more than one and include in the guidance notes that the OP should mention if the question is about the features that are available for everyone or about those that are restricted to G Suite users.

Another approach is to have one tag for Google consumer accounts and another tag for Google managed  / G Suite accounts and ask posters to include the corresponding tag.

---

Below are paired each G Suite main component listed in the question with the corresponding Stack Exchange Web Application tag.

- Communicate

  - Gmail                   [gmail](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/gmail),[google-apps-email](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/google-apps-email)
  - Hangouts                [google-hangouts](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/google-hangouts)
  - Calendar                [google-calendar](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/google-calendar)
  - Google+                 [google-plus](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/google-plus)
- Store

  - Drive                   [google-drive](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/google-drive)
- Collaborate

  - Docs                    [google-documents](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/google-documents)
  - Sheets                  [google-spreadsheets](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/google-spreadsheets), [google-spreasheets-query](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/google-spreasheets-query)
  - Slides                  [google-presentations](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/google-presentations)
  - Forms                   [google-forms](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/google-forms)
  - Sites                   [google-sites](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/google-sites)
- Manage

  - Admin
  - Vault                   [postini](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/postini)

## Other related tags

[google-account](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/google-account)
[google-apps](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/google-apps)
[google-apps-for-work](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/google-apps-for-work)
[google-apps-sync](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/google-apps-sync) No tag guidance.
[google-apps-script](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/google-apps-script)